# Internet Explorer 9 compatibilty issue

Tags: internet-explorer

My client's website which is www.sateri.com has problem regarding the Internet Explorer 9 compatibility. The website looks good in Firefox, Chrome and IE8 and below. But not in IE9. The problem is it's not display the text on the drop down menu.

Then, I tried all the methods to solve this problem I found on this Stack Overflow as well as on other sites. These are some meta tags I added.

> 1. meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=8, IE=9, IE=10"
> 2. meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"
> 3. meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE8; IE=EmulateIE9"

I put the meta tag before all other elements that aren't meta or title.

I also change the DOCTYPE to this: DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"

Then, I removed any comments in the head and below the DOCTYPE

However, the website still the same. The drop down menu still didn't displayed well.

Answer (score 0):

you have some minor markup errors...

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.sateri.com/main/en

but I can't see anything major except or the  tag in the  block.... should be avoided... yes utf-8 encoding...

You can test cufon in IE with Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, Accessibility button, check "Ignore font styles in web pages".... this will force IE to use its default web fonts instead o the cufon shims... from memory cufon had some issues with IE9... I think the solution was to add the x-ua IE=8 meta to force IE9 to use the IE8 rendering engine... 
then you may loose support for some of the html5 features you have in there.